# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm trying to reinstall magento 2.4 on my laptop.
when I did run :

> php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2ee --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --opensearch-timeout=1

I recieved a success message :

```
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_nx3opv
Nothing to import.
```

now, according to the official documentation, I should run :
http://localhost/magento2ee and expect to see the luma theme on. but it ahows this error:
[image]
same result if I try with /admin or index.php
[image]

may be worth to note, when Installing, I had an error:

> In PatchApplier.php line 172:
> Unable to apply data patch Magento\Theme\Setup\Patch\Data\RegisterThemes for module Magento_Theme.
> Original exception on message: Wrong file
> In Gd2.php line 70:
> Wrong file

i resolved it by adding `if(!file_exists($filename)) { // if file not exist }` function into  the gd2 file